# Solving the wave equation $u_{tt}=\alpha^2 u_{xx}$ given initial condition $u_t(x,0)=\sin{\frac{\pi x}{L}}+0.5 \sin{\frac{3 \pi x}{L}}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I want to solve the following IBVP:

> $$u_{tt}=\alpha^2 u_{xx} \space \space \space \space \space \space
>  0<x<L; \space \space \space \space \space \space0<t<\infty \\ BCs:
>  u(0,t)=0; u(L,t)=0\space \space \space \space \space \space 0<t<
> \infty \\ ICs:u(x,0)=\sin{\frac{\pi x}{L}}+0.5 \sin{\frac{3 \pi
>  x}{L}}; u_t(x,0)=0$$

The solution to the finite string problem is:

$$\boxed{u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin{\frac{n \pi x}{L}}[a_n \sin{\frac{n \pi \alpha t}{L}}+b_n \cos{\frac{n \pi \alpha t}{L}}]}$$

where:

$$\boxed{a_n=\frac{2}{n \pi \alpha} \int_0^L g(x)\sin{\frac{n \pi x}{L}} dx}$$

$$\boxed{b_n=\frac{2}{L} \int_0^L f(x) \sin{\frac{n \pi x}{L}} dx}$$

In this case $g(x)=0$ and $f(x)=\sin{\frac{\pi x}{L}}+0.5 \sin{\frac{3 \pi
 x}{L}}$.

$\implies a_n=0; \space \space \space b_n=\frac{2}{L}\int_0^L(\sin{\frac{\pi x}{L}}+0.5 \sin{\frac{3 \pi x}{L}})\sin{\frac{n \pi x}{L}} dx$

I am stuck here. I don't really know how to evaluate the integral without it becoming really messy. The solution is supposed to be:

$$u(x,t)=\sin{\frac{\pi x}{L}} \cos{\frac{\pi \alpha t}{L}}+\frac{1}{2}\sin{\frac{3 \pi x}{L}}\cos{\frac{3 \pi \alpha t}{L}}$$

I don't see how I can arrive at this solution. Doesn't the solution have to be an infinite series? Am I even doing this correctly?

Comment: What do you know about orthogonality?

Comment: The integral is an inner product.

Comment: Do you know how to take a Fourier transform?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The internet at our library just crashed. As far as I know I am not supposed to use the fourier transform here but I guess I could transform the pde and be left with a second order ODE in $t$. @spinoza I just checked the textbook and I found this: $$\int_0^1 \sin{(m \pi x)} \sin{(n \pi x)} dx=0 \text{if $m \not= n$} \\ \int_0^1 \sin{(m \pi x)} \sin{(n \pi x)} dx=\frac{1}{2} \text{if $m=n$}$$. So can I deduce that $n=1$ and $n=3$ are the only viable "$n$'s"?

Comment: Yes, this is the nice part: we don't actually have to do so many integrals because of othogonality!

Comment: @spinoza Ok this is starting to make a whole lot of sense. But the integrals all go from $0$ to $L$ and not just from $0$ to $1$. Does this change anything?

Comment: The short answer is yes, but this is accounted for by the factor $\frac{2}{L}$ in front of the integral, so the integral will be $1$ if $m=n$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: @spinoza So the $\frac{2}{L}$ and $\frac{2}{n \pi \alpha}$ infront of the integrals allow me to evaluate the integrals as if I was integrating from $0$ to $1$?

Comment: @spinoza I got the forumulas from Farlow's Partial Diff. Equations for Scientists and Engineers and he writes the integrals from $0$ to $L$ and not from $0$ to $1$. I am bit confused. Sholdn't the factor infront of the integral change the limits of integration

Comment: @bluemoon See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $L$ is given by the boundary conditions. It can be thought of as the length of a string. Observe that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\cos 2\theta&=\cos^2 \theta-\sin^2 \theta\\
&=(1-\sin^2 \theta)-\sin^2 \theta\\
&=1-2\sin^2 \theta.
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore $\sin^2 \theta=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\cos 2\theta}{2}.$ When $\theta=\frac{n\pi x}{L},$ this means
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^L(\sin \frac{n\pi x}{L})^2 dx&=\int_0^L\frac{1}{2}dx+\int_0^L -\frac{\cos \frac{2n\pi x}{L}}{2} dx\\
&=\frac{L}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^L\cos \frac{2n\pi x}{L} dx\\
&=\frac{L}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\Big[\frac{L}{2 n\pi}\sin \frac{2n\pi x}{L}\Big]_0^L\\
&=\frac{L}{2}-\frac{1}{2}(0-0)=\frac{L}{2}.
\end{aligned}
$$

We would like this integral to equal $1$, so we take this integral multiplied by $\frac{2}{L}$. Hence the definition of $b_n$ in your post.

Of course, for $m\ne n$, we still have
$$
\int_0^L\sin \frac{n\pi x}{L}\sin \frac{m\pi x}{L} dx=0,
$$
so that you only have to worry about $n=1$ and $n=3$ in your case.

The case where $L=1$ is just a (nice) example of the general case.

Comment: That helped me a lot. Thank you for your help and patience!